# фильтрация переменной $_POST

Tags: php

Как отфильтровать `$_POST['asd']`, что бы можно было вводить только текст?

Comment: Чтобы можно было "вводить только текст" - это вопрос к клиентской стороне, а конкретно к JavaScript. Чтобы в переменной был текст(?), то это вопрос к строчным функциям языка PHP. Да и интересно, как это "только текст" ? По-вашему, можно "вводить" объекты что ли?

Comment: Если вводит в форме, то фильтрация не сюда ставится а в форме.

Comment: Суть в том, что $asd может содержать php код или js код и все это будет помещено в бд. Как сделать так, что бы php вот такой вот код "<script>alert('sd')</script> обрезал и что то подобное, и пропускал только текст который несет информационный характер.

Comment: @Димон, а существует ли понятный компьютеру критерий «текста, который несёт информационный характер»?

Comment: @Димон, `<script>alert('sd')</script>` это тоже текст. Вы ж его сюда ввели, его никто не обрезал и в то же время, он не был выполнен. Вот так и надо поступать — не обрезать, а делать исполнение невозможным. См. мой ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Из комментариев понятно, что вы опасаетесь инъекции JS и PHP. Общепринятая практика такова:

- При **вводе** значение фильтруется только по предметной области: т.е. если это телефонный номер, например, то допустимы только определенные символы, а если это поле комментария, то там может быть *любой* текст.
- А при **выводе** значения пропускаются через htmlspecialchars() или htmlentities(). Таким образом, исполнение JS из пользовательского текста невозможно. Все известные шаблонизаторы умеют это делать.
- Кода на PHP вообще не надо опасться. Нереально его выполнить, если только вы сами этого не запрограммируете.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете преобразовать значение в строку, используя приведение `(string)`, либо функцию `strval()`.

Для обрезания тегов используйте функцию `strip_tags()`.

Comment: Можно ещё htmlspecialchars() использовать

Comment: @OmBird htmlspecialchars(),если я не путаю,преобразует некоторые символы в html-сущности.У автора несколько иная проблема.

Comment: Да, всё правильно. Я просто имел в виду, что, если юзер попробует ввести какие-нибудь теги (я так понял, автор этого боится), то они отобразятся в виде обычного текста, а обрабатываться не будут. И в обрезке не  будет необходимости.

Comment: @АндрейШелест, автор не сумел нормально сформулировать вопрос.   Не факт, что он сам знает о чем спрашивает. А OmBird правильно отметил: пользовательские данные становятся безопасными и при этом неиспорченными.

Answer (score 0):

`strip_tags()` + `htmlspecialchars()`
да и если фильтруете такие данные как email,домен и т.д. можете использовать 
`filter_var()`

Answer (score 0):

Вы сможете только проверить, является ли пост текстом, или является ли пост цифровым.

Вот пример

```
a="444"

if(ctype_digit(a))echo "ТУТ ЦИФРЫ ОДНИ"; else echo "ТУТ БУКВА СПРЯТАЛАСЬ";
```

Вспомнил только ctype_digit.

Вот официальный пример.

```
$strings = array('1820.20', '10002', 'wsl!12');
foreach ($strings as $testcase) {
    if (ctype_digit($testcase)) {
        echo "Строка $testcase состоит только из цифр.\n";
    } else {
        echo "Строка $testcase не состоит только из цифр.\n";
    }
}
```

Я показал простой.

Answer (score 0):

В php есть встроенные [функции фильтрации](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.filter.php). Примерно так вырежет из введенных данных все теги и младшие непечатные символы:

```
$var = filter_input(
    INPUT_POST,
    'asd',
    FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW
);
```

См. подробнее [типы фильтров](http://php.net/manual/ru/filter.filters.php), и [уточняющие флаги](http://php.net/manual/ru/filter.filters.flags.php).

Answer (score 0):

В добавлении к ответу про JS- и PHP- инъекции: возможно стоит и про **SQL-инъекции** почитать [что-нибудь](http://habrahabr.ru/post/148701/)